# Querying by a value in XML in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's say I have a column in a table where the datatype is XML.  I have a specific value I want query for in an xml tag that is unique(no repeating) in the XML.  How do I do this?

Something like:

```
select * from MyTable 
 where XMLColumn.TagImLookingAt.Value = @QueryValue
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE xmlcolumn.value('(/path/to/tag)[1]', 'int') = @QueryValue
```

Change the data type to whatever is appropriate.

For more info, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx) - specifically the methods available when dealing with the XML data type...